# Curvature of a spherical curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Show that a curve takes values in a sphere if and only if the curvature $k_n$ and $k_g$ of a parallel frame satisfy the equation of a line in the plane.
How can the radius of the sphere can be read off this equation?

I already tried to differentiate  $\Vert\gamma-a\Vert=r²$ and I am familiar with the structure equations. I also read this question [Prove that a curve is spherical iff it satisfies the relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198119/prove-that-a-curve-is-spherical-iff-it-satisfies-the-relation) but it didn't help me either.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: It's really not appropriate to call the curvatures $k_n$ and $k_g$ when you're talking about a parallel or *Bishop* frame. These terms only make sense when you're talking about a curve lying on a surface. See exercise 10 on p. 33 of my [differential geometry text](http://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).

Comment: But in this case the curve lies on a surface - the surface of the sphere. Apart from that I just quoted hte exercises from my differential geometry course. I'll look at your text, thx!

Comment: Oh, duh, sorry. But that only makes sense for the only if direction. So the point is that we can take (although we needn't) $\mathbf N_1 = \gamma$. The result holds for any Bishop frame.

Comment: Thx a lot. I think I can solve it now - I'll write it down later. By the way: your text is great!

Comment: Okay I've shown that the curvatures satisfy the equation of a line. I still have a problem with the other direction - my thought was that I just take the distance from curve to a fixed point and differentiate it, if equals zero then the distance is constant and this point is the centre of the sphere.

Comment: The problem is that you have no idea what point to use. The point is that $\gamma$ will lie on a sphere centered at $P$ if and only if $(\gamma-P)\cdot T = 0$ (why?). Supposing $ak_1+bk_2+1=0$, what can you say about $\alpha = \gamma - aN_1 - bN_2$?

Comment: @why?: because $(\gamma - P)\cdot(\gamma - P)=R²$ if I differentiate it I get $2(\gamma -P) \cdot T = 0$

Comment: Of course: And conversely by a well-known fact about integrating $0$. But this is used *everywhere* in differential geometry.

Comment: Now I would differentiate $\alpha = \gamma - aN_1 - bN_2$ and multiple it with $T$ and then I can substitute $N_1' \cdot T = -k_1$ and $N_2' \cdot T = -k_2$ and use the equation for the curvatures from above.

Comment: Finally I get the equation $\alpha' \cdot T = \gamma' \cdot T - 1$, hence $\alpha' \cdot T = 0$ where $\alpha = \gamma - P$. Therefore the curve $\gamma$ has to lie on a sphere.

Comment: Where did $P$ come from?

Comment: There is a combination of $N_1$ and $N_2$ which gives us $P=aN_1 + bN_2$. Tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No, you're not doing things right. The point of introducing $\alpha$ is to get $\alpha'=0$.

Comment: Am I right to the point where I followed that $\alpha \cdot T = 0$?

Comment: Okay, I think I have another approach: I choose $a$ and $b$ so that $\alpha'=0$ therefore it is constant. Now I show that $\alpha$ is in fact the centre of the sphere by differentiating: $(\alpha-\gamma) \cdot (\alpha-\gamma)=0$ and with this I know that $\gamma$ lies on the sphere with the centre $\alpha$.

Comment: Right. :) Now you have it!!

Comment: Thank you! You helped me a lot.