# show that $\phi'$ is zero

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus

let $\gamma: I \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^3} $ be a curve parameterized by arc length

We denote by $(\gamma(s),T(s),N(s),B(s))$ the frenet-frame.

suppose we assume the following :

1. $$\gamma''(s) \neq 0\;\;\forall s\in I$$
2. $$\tau(s) \neq 0\;\;\forall s\in I$$ here $\tau$ represents the torsion of $\gamma$
3. $$\rho'(s) \neq 0\;\;\forall s\in I $$ here $\rho = \frac{1}{\kappa}$ where $\kappa$ represents the curvature of $\gamma$
4. $$\rho^2+\sigma^2(\frac{d\rho}{d s})^2 = \text{a constant number}$$ here $\sigma = \frac{1}{\tau}$
5. $$\phi(s) = \gamma(s) +\rho(s)N(s) +\sigma(s)\frac{d\rho}{d s}(s)B(s)$$

show that : $\phi'(s) = 0 $ and conclude that there exists an $\Omega \in \mathbb{R^3}$ such that $||\gamma(s) - \Omega|| = \text{a constant number}$

---

my attempt : from 5

$$\phi'(s) = \gamma'(s) + \frac{d\rho}{d s}(s)N(s)+\rho(s)N'(s)+(\sigma(s)\frac{d\rho}{d s}(s))'B(s) + \sigma(s)\frac{d\rho}{d s}(s)B'(s) $$

by differentiating 4 you get :

$2\frac{d\rho}{d s}(s)\rho(s) + 2(\sigma(s)\frac{d\rho}{d s}(s))'\sigma(s)\frac{d\rho}{d s}(s) = 0 $

from now on I'm stuck I couldn't find a relation between the above equation and what I'm trying to prove any help/hints will be greatly appreciated. thanks !

Comment: First of all, have you identified that $\rho$ is the radius of curvature and that you are asked to prove that the curve is situated on a sphere ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I've never heard of the notion of 'radius of curvature' before 
I will google it

Comment: @JeanMarie a curve is situated on a sphere if it components $x,y,z$
satisfiy the equation $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2 = R^2$

I guess you're telling me that $\gamma$ satisfies such an equation where $R=\rho$ , right ?

Comment: I just translated in plain terms what $||\gamma(s) - \Omega|| = \text{a constant number}$ means.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/198119)

Comment: Just after noting that $\gamma'$ has length 1, you change $T'(s)$ into $\gamma'(s)$ (following the first right-double-arrow) which is wrong.

Comment: @JohnHughes thanks for noticing 
I shoudve changed it into $\kappa(s)N(s)$

Comment: You can do so now, using the "edit" option at the bottom of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: take your first equation 
$$
\phi'(s) = \gamma'(s) + \frac{d\rho}{d s}(s)N(s)+\rho(s)N'(s)+(\sigma(s)\frac{d\rho}{d s}(s))'B(s) + \sigma(s)\frac{d\rho}{d s}(s)B'(s)
$$
and consider applying the Frenet formulas (which you've never used so far). For instance, you can replace $N'$ with $-\kappa T + \sigma B$ (I'm going to delete all the "s" arguments to make things simpler):
\begin{align}
\phi' &= \gamma' + \frac{d\rho}{d s}N+\rho  N'+(\sigma\frac{d\rho}{d s})'B + \sigma\frac{d\rho}{d s}B'\\
\phi' &= \gamma' + \frac{d\rho}{d s}N+\rho  (-\kappa T + \sigma B) +(\sigma\frac{d\rho}{d s})'B + \sigma\frac{d\rho}{d s}B'\\
\phi' &= \gamma' + \frac{d\rho}{d s}N- \rho  \kappa T + \rho \sigma B +(\sigma\frac{d\rho}{d s})'B + \sigma\frac{d\rho}{d s}B'
\end{align}
Then you notice that $\rho \kappa = 1$, and things simplify a little. Do the same for $B'$, and maybe it'll get you somewhere. (Also: go ahead and write out the product rule for the second-to-last term.)